# jquery selector to remove certain elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a list of pages each have following section of code

```
<div class="A">
  <br>
  some text.
  some <b>more</b> text.
  <br>
  More text to follow <a href="link">here</a>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="B">
    <div class="z">
     <span class="y">text</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="C">text</div>
  <p>text</p>
  <div class="D">text</div>
</div>
```

I want to remove the tags from B to D. I tried `slice()` and didnt work well. I cant use `nth-last-child()` since the number of child div tags varies in some pages. Is it possible to find a jquery selector like `$('.A').not('.B,.C,.D').html()` or `$('.A').not('.B to .D').html()` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Taking reference from answers of dippas and David Thomas and another [source](https://www.itsupportguides.com/knowledge-base/website-tips/jquery-how-to-get-element-text-without-child-elements/), I found the right jquery selector that works in the application I use.

```
$('.A').clone().children('.B,.C,p,.D').remove().end().html()
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have a typo, it is not `<a href="link">here</b>` but `<a href="link">here</a>`

Then you can use `find()`

```js
$('.A').find('.B,.C,.D').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="A">
  <br>
  some text.
  some <b>more</b> text.
  <br>
  More text to follow <a href="link">here</a>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="B">
    <div class="z">
     <span class="y">text</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="C">text</div>
  <p>text</p>
  <div class="D">text</div>
</div>
```

Other way is using `children()`

```js
$('.A').children('.B,.C,.D').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="A">
  <br>
  some text.
  some <b>more</b> text.
  <br>
  More text to follow <a href="link">here</a>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="B">
    <div class="z">
     <span class="y">text</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="C">text</div>
  <p>text</p>
  <div class="D">text</div>
</div>
```

---

you can do this with pure CSS

```css
.A>div:nth-last-of-type(-n+3) {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div class="A">
  <br>
  some text.
  some <b>more</b> text.
  <br>
  More text to follow <a href="link">here</a>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="B">
    <div class="z">
     <span class="y">text</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="C">text</div>
  <p>text</p>
  <div class="D">text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `find()` didnt return any result and `children()` removed everything except B's children. Couldnt use `nth-last-of-type()` since sometimes the no of div varies (updating this to my question).

Comment: I used your markup and it works in the snippets. Run them

Comment: yes, it works in your code snippet, but its not working in my application nor in the browser console.

Comment: then your markup is not the same as this, or is something else wrong

Answer (score 1):

While dippas has already posted a [perfectly good jQuery answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51232539/82548), it seems worth adding a plain JavaScript alternative:

```
// find the parent element, here we use document.querySelector()
// which returns the first (if any) or null (if none) node
// matching he supplied selector:
document.querySelector('.A')

// from there we find the relevant descendent elements, using a
// CSS selector which returns a NodeList containing all elements
// matching the supplied selector(s):
.querySelectorAll('.B, .C, .D')

// using NodeList.prototype.forEach() to iterate over the
// NodeList result supplied from Element.querySelectorAll():
.forEach(

  // an Arrow function to apply to each of the Nodes in the
  // NodeList over which we're iterating; 'child' is a reference
  // to the current Node of the NodeList.

  // here we call ChildNode.remove() to remove the node:
  child => child.remove()
);
```

```js
document.querySelector('.A').querySelectorAll('.B, .C, .D').forEach(child => child.remove());
```

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.B,
.C,
.D {
  background-color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="A">
  <br> some text. some <b>more</b> text.
  <br> More text to follow <a href="link">here</a>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="B">
    <div class="z">
      <span class="y">text</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="C">text</div>
  <p>text</p>
  <div class="D">text</div>
</div>
```

References:

- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`ChildNode.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).